# Statistical modelling books that DON'T go easy on the math

Tags: inference, modeling, references

I'm looking for a book on statistical modelling techniques that doesn't skimp on the derivations, probability theory, calc and linear algebra. A lot of books seem to be designed for people who don't want to work through the math, but I think this approach doesn't lead to a satisfactory understanding of statistical techniques. I have an understanding of mathematical stats via Hogg et al's Intro to Math Stats and I'm looking for something that will describe the uses of GLM, GAMs, hierarchical models and other techniques for statistical **inference**, not just prediction (i.e. ML algorithms).

Something in the style of Elements of Statistical Learning would be great. I've read it, but I find that text leans a little too much toward non-interpretable models (SVM, random forests etc). The same argument applies to the Bishop book. I have a copy of the Gelman et al. Bayesian Data Analysis book, which looks good, but I'd like to know what else is out there.

Comment: I gave an answer to a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/524526/321865). The other answers to this question are also good suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. That question isn't quite the same as mine. The poster there was after books on the fundamentals, whereas I'm quite comfortable with them and would like to know more about modelling. The econometrics books you list look like a good start!